# How to create thumbnail from video in PHP in shared hosting?

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I am on shared hosting, so I can't use `ffmpeg`.

I need to create thumbnails of video uploaded with REST API. Hence it is not possible to use HTML canvas to generate video preview.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What API are you using, it is highly possible that the API itself can be queried after video processing - it may return to you the thumbnail.

Comment: Please show us your attempts so far